# mysql subquery returns more than 1 row getting multiple rows of a single user

Tags: mysql

I have a user table with `user_id` and name as fields, I also have a `user_images` tables with `user_id` and image fields which has multiple user images. I need a query which gives me user name and all the images from `user_image` table

user

```
user_id | user_name
1       | mia
2       | arif
```

user_image

```
user_image_id | user_id   | image
    1              1          a.jpg
    2              1          b.jpg
    3              2          c.jpg
    4              2          d.jpg
```

I need output with `user_name` and all the images of that user.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a service where you have developers work for you for free :)

Comment: this was actually a part of a problem if i had to ask the question with all the other criteria it would have been very confusing so i dint give the complex query out here..and thanx to ppl who have answered below its been solved now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT user.username,user_image.image
FROM user 
INNER JOIN user_image 
ON user.user_id = user_image.user_id;
```

INNER JOIN combines the two tables based ON their common column which in this case is user_id.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query then you will get if some users don't have the images that information also this query will display with null.

select tu.user_name,tui.image from tab_user tu left join tab_user_image tui on tu.user_id=tui.user_id;

Answer (score 0):

SELECT u.user_name,m.image from user u  join user_image m on u.user_id=m.user_id where u.user_id=2

Join two table and then check with user that you want to get the images by using (where u.user_id=2)